# How I can update external property file spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee-6, properties-file

I have a problem when I want to update my external property file

here is the external property file :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_cours

spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.username=root

server.port=1112

spring.application.name=gestionDesCours


spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
prefix=abc

suffix=abd

message=welcome in default profile
```

and here is my class :

```
package DAHIBI.controller;
import javax.naming.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/GestionDesCours")
public class UpdatePropertiesGestionCours {
    @PostMapping("/Default")
    public PropertiesConfiguration main( @RequestBody Constants cns )
            throws org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException, ConfigurationException {
        PropertiesConfiguration properties = new PropertiesConfiguration(
                "C://configrepo//localconfig//gestionDesCours.properties");
        properties.setProperty("prefix", cns.getPrefix());
        properties.setProperty("suffix", cns.getSuffix());
        properties.setProperty("message", cns.getMessage());
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", cns.getUsername());
        properties.save();
        return properties;

    }
```

and the attributes on another class like that :

```
package DAHIBI.controller;
public class Constants {
    
    String prefix;
    String suffix;
    String defaultValue;
    String message;
    String  username;
    
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }
    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }
    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }
    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }
    public String getDefaultValue() {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    public void setDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
}
```

the problem is spring.datasource.username doesn't take the new value, he returns null always!
The properties "prefix", "suffix", "message" they take the new values but spring.datasource.username returns null with error ! If anyone can help me please, I will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Here everything is working. Debug your application and see if username is null on the input object.

If username is null just check the body of your request and see if username is correctly spelled.

Comment: yes the username is null on the input object